# Regex валидация ввода

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

В регулярках, особенно на Пайтоне, не особо разбираюсь, и хотел бы спросить, какой правильный синтаксис должен быть, ибо не доганяю.
К примеру, есть шаблон - строка "Слово" приписанный к переменной (text) и хочу чтобы можно было валидировать это слово и в разных местах (`....слово...`), и с разными окончаниями(`словоааа, слово:)`). Я уже все перепробовал `^` и `.`, но чёт не очень выходит. 
На выходе должно быть что-то if input == text -> do something.
Спасибо

Comment: "регулярки, особенно в Пайтоне" - ничем особенным не отличаются. это вам не perl. Вы уверены, что вам нужны регулярки? точно метод `in` не подойдет?

Comment: Это поиск подстроки.

Comment: Отличаются, но незначительно. Любые паттерны, начинающиеся с `?P` являются расширениями python. Например, `'(?P<name>...)'`

Comment: Мне больше всего нужно было это - `r".*слово.*"` и `re.findall(searching,text,inputtext,re.IGNORECASE):` Просто так куча методов была я не знал что и как юзать, как писать, теперь понимаю =)

Answer (score 2):

Регулярка для "слово" в любом контексте:

```
.*слово.*
```

Если нужен всё таки не любой контекст, а подстрока "слово" в любом слове:

```
\b\S*слово\S*\b
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ;)